# Is there a way to improve how the Grails 4 JSON converter handles LocalDate objects?

Tags: json, grails, localdate

In my Grails 4.0.5 application I have a domain class `AssignedItem`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
class AssignedItem
{
    LocalDate dateAssigned
}
```

When I call my controller method `/assignedItem/show/1` which uses the JSON view for my domain class (`_assignedItem.gson`), then the response looks good:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "dateAssigned": "2015-12-30"
}
```

But in my service method where I convert an `AssignedItem` to JSON in order to send it to an ActiveMQ queue, the JSON ends up being needlessly complex.

Service method

```
import grails.converters.JSON

void sendSampleData() {
    AssignedItem assignedItem = AssignedItem.first()
    JSON json = assignedItem as JSON
    String jsonString = json.toString(true)
    jmsService.send(queue: assignedItemQueueName, jsonString)
}
```

In the above code, `jsonString is as follows:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "dateAssigned": {
      "dayOfWeek": {
         "enumType": "java.time.DayOfWeek",
         "name": "THURSDAY"
      },
      "month": {
         "enumType": "java.time.Month",
         "name": "DECEMBER"
      },
      "dayOfMonth": 31,
      "dayOfYear": 365,
      "era": {
         "enumType": "java.time.chrono.IsoEra",
         "name": "CE"
      },
      "year": 2015,
      "monthValue": 12,
      "chronology": {
         "calendarType": "iso8601",
         "id": "ISO"
      },
      "leapYear": false
   }
}
```

Is there a way to fix the behavior of `assignedItem as JSON` or should I be converting the `AssignedItem` into JSON some other way?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use your `_assignedItem.gson` template instead of using `as JSON`?

Comment: Nope. If there is a way to use my `_assignedItem.gson` template in my service to get a JSON string, I would happily use it! Before posting my question, I did a quick Google search to see if there was a way to do just that but I did not find any results.

Comment: I think you should be able to use `_assignedItem.gson`. Please check out the `JsonViewTemplateEngine` section in the Grails GSON Views docs: http://views.grails.org/latest/#_the_jsontemplateengine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @puneet-behl pointing this out to me, I was able to use the [`JsonViewTemplateEngine`](http://views.grails.org/latest/#_the_jsontemplateengine) in my service method so that my JSON view template (`_assignedItem.gson`) was used to generate the JSON:

```
void sendSampleData() {
    AssignedItem assignedItem = AssignedItem.first()
    Template t = templateEngine.resolveTemplate('/assignedItem/_assignedItem')
    def writable = t.make(assignedItem: assignedItem)
    def sw = new StringWriter()
    writable.writeTo( sw )
    String jsonString = sw.toString()
    jmsService.send(queue: assignedItemQueueName, jsonString)
}
```